# How to get the full path to system32 directory with c++?

Tags: c++, windows

Although most of the time it's `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, but sometimes it can be in `D` partition or alike, how to get it programatically?

Answer (score 7):

You can call the Windows API function [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(v=VS.85).aspx) and ask for `CSIDL_SYSTEM`.

In Windows Vista and later, you can call [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(v=VS.85).aspx) and ask for `FOLDERID_System`.  `SHGetFolderPath` is just a wrapper around this function in later versions of Windows, but if you want your software to run on Windows XP, you'll need to use `SHGetFolderPath`.

Answer (score 4):

```
UINT WINAPI GetSystemDirectory(
  _Out_  LPTSTR lpBuffer,
  _In_   UINT uSize
);
```

You can use this as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[GetWindowsDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724454(VS.85).aspx) also is a possibility depending on the OS/purpose. Clearly SHGetFolderPath seems to be the MS recommended way

Comment: Actually, it would be GetSystemDirectory().